# Selenium chrome failed to start

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Running the most basic selenium test I can think of.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            String path = @"D:\Selenium Webdrivers\ChromeDriver\";
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = new ChromeDriver(path);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using,

- Chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 m
- ChromeDriver 2.22
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1
- Selenium WebDriver Support Classes 2.53.1
- win10 (recent upgrade)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome and removing the user profiles.

the error I get is,

> Test Name:    TestMethod1 Test
>   FullName: UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 Test
>   Source:   c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs : line 13
>   Test Outcome: Failed Test Duration:   0:00:01.3305496
>
> Result Message:    Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
>   threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error:
>   chrome failed to start   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933
>   (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.10586 x86_64) Result StackTrace:  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String
>   chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String
>   chromeDriverDirectory)    at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
>   in c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 15

Comment: `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` will work correctly. Seems to be just chrome.

Comment: Is there an older version of Chrome lying around somewhere on the machine you're testing on that WebDriver's picking up and trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is now resolved. I was not running visual studio as an administrator. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Try throwing your chromedriver.exe in your project/solution folder and then appropriately changing your path.  That should fix the issue for you.

note: FireFoxDriver works successfully because it's included in the Selenium packages, which is also within your project solution.