# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Just to show that I have done my due diligince, I have already either tried the suggested answers or at least read them over and tried to understand, for the following questions:

[Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is)

[The process started from chrome location C:\..\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009351/the-process-started-from-chrome-location-c-chrome-application-chrome-exe-is)

[Selenium python library via docker, Chrome error failed to start: exited abnormally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710664/selenium-python-library-via-docker-chrome-error-failed-to-start-exited-abnorma)

[Chrome crashes when using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024812/chrome-crashes-when-using-selenium) (No answer posted but I still looked it over)

[How to fix "usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed" error in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862006/how-to-fix-usr-bin-google-chrome-is-no-longer-running-so-chromedriver-is-assum)
- For this one I substituted the '/usr/bin/google-chrome' with '/etc/alternatives/google-chrome', still didn't work.

[The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed for Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624355/the-process-started-from-chrome-location-usr-bin-google-chrome-is-no-longer-run)

[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed with ChromeDriver and Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112188/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-fa)

[python linux selenium: chrome not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008622/python-linux-selenium-chrome-not-reachable)

[unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed(selenium ,headless mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373674/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashedselenium-headless-mode)

[python selenium: WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742235/python-selenium-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable)

[Selenium chrome failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635496/selenium-chrome-failed-to-start)

[WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor)

[Getting "Chrome not reachable" error while executing test scripts in Selenium Grid With Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729524/getting-chrome-not-reachable-error-while-executing-test-scripts-in-selenium-gr)

[Selenium webdriver error Chrome failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344876/selenium-webdriver-error-chrome-failed-to-start)

[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (headless chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830193/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-c)

[Python : Selenium - Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354429/python-selenium-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor)

I am getting a common error that I have seen here on Stack Overflow, when running Selenium with Python on my Amazon Linux server I get the following results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-selenium-chrome.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.i
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9515')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will seearch path.i
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)  # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5)  # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

I am using Google Chrome version 79.0.3945.130, and the corresponding chromedriver version ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 as speicified in https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Additional info, if I just run google-chrome from the command line, I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx bin]$ pwd
/usr/bin
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx bin]$ google-chrome
Segmentation fault
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with  the latest chrome driver version?

Comment: Hi Muzzamil, yes I tried it with the chromedriver version 80.0.3987.16.  Still got the same results.

Comment: Okay and sequence of chrome driver binary path and chrome options is correct in webdriver.Chrome()? I think path should come first and then options.

Comment: Hi Muzzami, I just reversed the order and tried driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options) that still didn't work.

Comment: Anyone is getting this error in github actions( deployment section)

Comment: I received this error in GitHub actions and wrote an answer to it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70341965/6697714  @AnupamHaldkar

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the discussion in [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276), the expected default location of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) is:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

**Note**: For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary.

So ideally, the following minimal code block should have worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

But it seems, when you try to initiate a *Chrome* session manually, *Segmentation fault* occurs i.e. crashes as follows:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx bin]$ pwd
/usr/bin
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx bin]$ google-chrome
Segmentation fault
```

---

### Segmentation fault

[Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (shortened as `segfault`) or access violation is a fault or failure condition raised by hardware with memory protection, notifying an operating system that the software has attempted to access a restricted area of memory. The OS kernel will, in response, usually perform some corrective action, generally passing the fault on to the offending process (your script) by sending the process a signal.

In short, it’s a helper mechanism to restrict programs/scripts from corrupting the memory which does not belong to it. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault).

---

### Reason and Solutions

The pottential reasons and solutions are:

- *Chrome* is not at all installed within the system, so you have to install *Chrome*
- *Chrome* is not installed at the default location, so you have to pass the correct location of *chrome* executable through `binary_location` property.
- The symlink `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to the actual Chrome binary got corrupted, so you may have to create the symlink.
- The user doesn't have required access rights `/usr/bin/google-chrome`, so you have provide the access rights.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, I tried changing the ownership of /usr/bin/google-chrome to ec2-user:apache, and I still get the segmentation fault.

Comment: Just to do my due diligence, I have installed it as the solution suggested, with the path to the working symbolic link correctly specified in the code (options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome')

Comment: @BrentHeigold Are you able to spin up a Chrome browsing context manually?

Comment: Hi Debanjan, it's installed remotely on my AWS instance, so I can only run it command-line, and I get that same segmentation fault as described in my original question.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @BrentHeigold Seems something is still missing. If you can't achieve it manually due to OS kernel complaining about `segfault`, there's nothing much Selenium can do on top of it. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Ok sounds great, thanks for at least helping me narrow down my troubleshooting options.

Comment: @BrentHeigold did you get a solution that works? I'm finding I get this issue for some tests that run once I upgraded to v81 of chrome and chromedriver.

Comment: Hi dragonsfire, I did get a solution but it was a while ago so I don't remember what I did.

Comment: @dragonsfire Did you find the solution?

Comment: I received this error in GitHub actions and wrote an answer to it here stackoverflow.com/a/70341965/6697714  @mouse_freak

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem, just remove --headless line and it's work well.