# GitLab's CI/CD pipelines: Selenium Chrome driver failed to start: exited abnormally or google-chrome is no longer running, Chrome has crashed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am running git lab ci cd pipeline for selenium Python UI automated tests. My tests are passing ok on my local. I have initialized Google Chrome using below code

```py
driver = chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

When I am running GitLab job, my pipeline is failing with below error

[image]

Below if the GitLab runner I can see used while running :
[image]

I also tried to used remote driver and headless mode-
In headless mode most of tests are failing. In remote mode, it not instantiating driver. Remove driver code as below

```py
elif self.browser == 'remote':
driver = webdriver.Remote(options=webdriver.ChromeOptions(), command_executor='http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub')
```

I am not sure if its happening due to gitlab runner. Or Do I need to create my custom gitlab runner to run on specific machine.
I am running selenium UI tests , so not sure runner which is used in my case don't have facility to run in GUI mode.

I found similar issue here- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Python on Amazon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081937/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashed-erro)

Tried below code but still same issue

```py
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
    executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

I am spinning image with -Docker executor with image joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.8

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing below options:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

For more inspirations go to:
[WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as yours. My root issue, however, is because the chrome browser is not found in the /usr/bin/google-chrome. My solution is very much inspired by this post right here [How to install chrome-webdriver on GitLab CI/CD](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/46994). As of now, the stable version of chrome is 119.0.6045.105-1 on Ubuntu, make sure your driver's version is compatible with your driver.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
  before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y default-jre
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y wget unzip curl

  # Install or update Google Chrome
  - CHROME_VERSION="119.0.6045.105-1"
  # Install Google Chrome
  - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
  - dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb || apt --fix-broken install -y
  - google-chrome-stable --version
```

Just my 2 cents! :D